# Some numbers are getting truncated. I would like to pull all numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to parse only numbers from a string.  My code must be pretty close, but something is off here, because several numbers in the last string are being truncated, although the first two strings seem fine.

Here is my code.

```
Drop Table SampleData
Create table SampleData
(id int, factor varchar(100))

insert into #source_Policy values (1 ,'AAA 1.058 (Protection Class)')
insert into #source_Policy values (2, 'BBB0.565 (Construction) ')
insert into #source_Policy values ( 3, 'CCCCC   1.04890616 (Building Limit Rel')


Select *
From SampleData 


;with processTable as (
    select id, factor, num    
    from SampleData    
  
           cross apply (
            select (select C + ''
            from (select N, substring(factor, N, 1) C from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) Num(N)   where N<=datalength(factor)) t
            where PATINDEX('%[0-9.]%',C)> 0
            order by N
            for xml path(''))
        ) p0 (num)  
) 


SELECT id, factor, num
FROM processTable
```

This is the result that I get.

[image]

In the num column, instead of `1.04`, I would like to see the full precision, so: `1.04890616`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think something like this:

```
select s.*, v2.numstr
from sampledata s cross apply
     (values (stuff(factor, 1, patindex('%[0-9]%', factor) - 1, ''))) v(str) cross apply
     (values (left(v.str, patindex('%[^0-9.]%', v.str + 'x') - 1))) v2(numstr);
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8233e/4) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: When I tried that, I got this: The correlation name 'v' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause.  I understand the need for the Cross Apply, but I don't know the rest well enough to troubleshoot this thing.

Comment: @ASH . . . I fixed the typos and added a fiddle.

Comment: Ah, it works!  I tried something like that, but I had a typo too, so of course it didn't work.  Thanks for the assist!!